# Reorder WooCommerce variation dropdowns (not re-order attribute terms)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a store with many simple products and a few variable ones. One of the variable products has three variable attributes and therefore, three `<select>` lists to choose from:

[image: Screenshot showing three WooCommerce variation dropdown lists.]

What I need is to reverse the order that the dropdowns appear in, like this:

- ISObus
- Tractor Type
- Mounting Brackets

All my searching has turned up only methods for re-ordering the `<option>` attribute terms. To be clear, this isn't what I need.

Here's an example of the markup:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="pa_mounting-brackets">Mounting Brackets</label></td>
            <td class="value">
                <!-- A select element with many option elements -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="pa_tractor-type">Tractor Type</label></td>
            <td class="value">
                <!-- A select element with many option elements -->
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="pa_isobus">ISObus</label></td>
            <td class="value">
                    <!-- A select element with two option elements -->
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="label"></td>
            <td class="value">
                <div class="single_variation_price_reset">
                    <div class="single_variation_wrap">
                        <div class="avada-variation single_variation" style="display: none;"></div>
                    </div>

                    <a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: hidden;">Clear selection</a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can reorder the table rows using CSS `display: flex;` and the `order` property, but there is no unique identifier on each `<tr>` element. I have to target my CSS solely based on the order of the elements using nth selectors.

Is there a UI or filter-based method for achieving this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

As is so often the case, putting the question in words led me to a kind of solution. My store is using Avada and the HTML in question comes from one of the theme's templates, not vanilla WooCommerce.

I copied /wp-content/themes/Avada/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php to my child theme, /wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php and found the following:

**Original:**

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>">
```

I copied `for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>"` from the `<label>` element and pasted it into the `<tr>` element above, changing `for` to `class`.

**Modified:**

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>">
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>">
```

This gives me some selectors to aim my CSS at. Here's my CSS to reorder using flex:

```
.single-product.woocommerce .variations > tbody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.single-product.woocommerce .variations > tbody > tr {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    order: 99;
}

.single-product.woocommerce .variations > tbody .pa_isobus {
    order: 1;
}

.single-product.woocommerce .variations > tbody .pa_tractor-type {
    order: 2;
}

.single-product.woocommerce .variations > tbody .pa_mounting-brackets {
    order: 3;
}

.single-product.woocommerce .variations > tbody > tr > td {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

I'm still interested to know if there is a simpler, better solution if you have one.